# How do I fix the following? Image not found. Whilst trying to using MySQL in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

So I think i originally installed rubygems using macports and now that I have updated it without using macports I get the following errors whilst trying to use MySQL.

```
rails s
```

Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

Click the link below for the full output:

https://skitch.com/stevancw/ri8qa/terminal-bash-bash-94x23

---

Does anyone know how to fix this or what I have done wrong?

---

These are my configs and versions.

---

.bash_profile

https://skitch.com/stevancw/ri8qm/bash-profile

---

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.10, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1
Which mysql
'~$ which mysql
/usr/local/mysql/bin//mysql
~$'

---

1.6.2
Which gem
'~$ which gem
/usr/bin/gem
~$ '

---

ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10.6.0]
Which ruby
'~$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
~$'

---

Rails 3.0.5
Which rails
~$ which rails
/usr/bin/rails
~$

Answer (score 0):

Mybe you should use `mysql` gem instead of `mysql2`

Just remove from your `Gemfile` this line

```
gem `myslq2`
```

and add this

```
gem `mysql`
```

and run `bundle install`

Comment: Could do but then I would have to re-config rails to run on MySQL. Wanted to use the latest.

Comment: No you won't. It is similar Mysql adapter. Just try it :)

Comment: `mysql` and `mysql2` are two different implementations, not two different versions.

Comment: It is two different libraries for one ordinary MySQL - so configs will be the same, isnt it?

Comment: Not entirely sure- I think you need to configure the Gemfile in rails to use MySQL instead of MySQL2- have not tried it though. Editing the gemfile is no big deal anyway.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!

Rename the following:

```
/usr/local/mysql/lib$ sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

Works and now I am able to start a server.
Anyone know why this works or why it was a problem???

Comment: http://freddyandersen.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/mysql-5-5-snow-leopard-and-rails/

Cheers Freddy!!!